# Terminate command after keyword in output in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to send a SIGKILL if a certain keyword is shown in the output of the command. Eg, if issue the following command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-250:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=109 time=0.687 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=109 time=0.704 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=109 time=0.711 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=109 time=0.809 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=109 time=0.727 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=109 time=0.835 ms
^C
```

After seeing the output **"icmp_seq=6"** I'd like the command to automatically halt. I know that ***ping 8.8.8.8 -c 6*** will have the same results, but it's just for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping 8.8.8.8 | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    [[ $line =~ icmp_seq=6 ]] && kill -9 $(pidof ping)
done
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner version of what I wrote, and it has the bonus of avoiding the creation of a file.

Comment: Is it possible to "de-pipe" the while loop to avoid using the sub-shell process?

Comment: I cannot figure out a good way to avoid using a subprocess regardless of the language. One possibility may be to write your own `ping` clone and embed it in your main process to watch the output of the `ping` clone.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is redirect the command output to a file, then set up a loop to `grep` the file for the particular string you want. If the `grep` succeeds, then end the loop and kill the process. Such a script for `ping` might look like this:

**THIS HAS A BUG IN IT**

```
ping www.google.com > output 2> error &

while [ true ]; do
    grep "icmp_seq=6" output
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
done

echo "sequence found, killing program"

pid=`pgrep ping` # get the PID of ping so we can kill it
kill -9 ${pid}
```

**Update:** It just occurred to me that this script has a downfall in that it will run infinitely if the search text never appears (and it will actually continue to run infinitely even after the candidate program terminates, or the program dies immediately on startup). Thus, here's an improved script that accounts for all of that:

```
ping www.google.com > output 2> error & # the & makes the command a background process so execution of other commands isn't blocked

pid=`pgrep ping`

while [ ! -z ${pid} ]; do # check if pid contains anything - if so, the ping command is still running
    grep "icmp_seq=6" output
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "sequence found, killing program"
        kill -9 ${pid}
        exit 0
    fi

    pid=`pgrep ping`
done

echo "Sequence not found"
```

**Optimization update:** Because I'm OCD about this stuff, this script can get bogged down if there's a lot of output because `grep` has to sift through all of it. Thus, my optimization suggestion would be to use `tail -1 output` and then pipe the output to `grep`, resulting in this script:

```
ping www.google.com > output 2> error & # the & makes the command a background process so execution of other commands isn't blocked

pid=`pgrep ping`

while [ ! -z ${pid} ]; do # check if pid contains anything - if so, the ping command is still running
    tail -1 output | grep "icmp_seq=6"
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "sequence found, killing program"
        kill -9 ${pid}
        exit 0
    fi

    pid=`pgrep ping`
done

echo "Sequence not found"
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but maybe to avoid conflicts with other `ping`s running in parallel, `pid=$!` could be used.

Comment: @ChristianTapia It's a good suggestion, but it wouldn't work inside of the loop.